# ¿Cómo puedo obtener las direcciones IP concretas desde las que se envía o recibe un paquete en base a un proceso previamente seleccionado?

Tags: python, python-3.7

**PROBLEMA**

Al ejecutar el siguiente código, en el que ya se ha seleccionado un proceso que utiliza la red en base a su PID. Muestra los puertos, así como las direcciones Internet Protocol locales y de destino que utiliza el proceso.

Ahora bien. Estoy intentando esnifar el tráfico sólo de este proceso, pero, en vez de esnifar el tráfico únicamente de este proceso, parece que hay interferencias con otros procesos y se muestran paquetes que no son originales del proceso seleccionado.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

**CÓDIGO**

```
def obtener_procesos_con_conexion():
    procesos_con_conexion = []
    conexiones_activas = psutil.net_connections(kind='inet')
    
    for conexion in conexiones_activas:
        if conexion.laddr and conexion.raddr:
            proceso = psutil.Process(conexion.pid)
            procesos_con_conexion.append({
                'pid': conexion.pid,
                'nombre': proceso.name(),
                'puerto_local': conexion.laddr.port,
                'puerto_remoto': conexion.raddr.port
            })
    
    return procesos_con_conexion

def seleccionar_proceso(pid):
    try:
        proceso_seleccionado = psutil.Process(pid)
        return {
            'pid': proceso_seleccionado.pid,
            'nombre': proceso_seleccionado.name(),
            'puertos': proceso_seleccionado.connections()
        }
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        return None

def imprimir_paquetes(packet):
    print(f"Paquete enviado desde {packet[IP].src} a {packet[IP].dst}")
    #packet.show()

def main():

    # Obtener procesos con conexión
    procesos_con_conexion = obtener_procesos_con_conexion()
    
    print("Procesos con conexión:")
    for proceso in procesos_con_conexion:
        if proceso['pid'] == 0:
            pass
        else:
            print(f"PID: {proceso['pid']}\tNombre: {proceso['nombre']}\tPuerto local: {proceso['puerto_local']}\tPuerto remoto: {proceso['puerto_remoto']}")
    
    # Seleccionar un proceso con conexión
    pid_seleccionado = int(input("\nIngrese el PID del proceso que desea seleccionar: "))
    proceso_seleccionado = seleccionar_proceso(pid_seleccionado)
    
    if proceso_seleccionado:
        print("\nProceso seleccionado:")
        print(f"PID: {proceso_seleccionado['pid']}\tNombre: {proceso_seleccionado['nombre']}")
        print("\nPuertos en uso")
        for conexion in proceso_seleccionado['puertos']:
            print(f"Local: {conexion.laddr} \tRemoto: {conexion.raddr}")
        iniciar_captura_de_paquetes = input("\nIniciar captura de paquetes Y/n: ")
        if iniciar_captura_de_paquetes == "Y" or "y":
            # Iniciar la captura de paquetes
            print("\nCapturando paquetes:")
            sniff(filter=f"src host {proceso_seleccionado['nombre']}", prn=imprimir_paquetes)
            time.sleep(200)
    else:
        print("El PID ingresado no corresponde a un proceso con conexión.")
```